# Does empty clear data from elem in jquery

Tags: jquery

```
//html structure
    <div id='outer'>
       <div id='inner'>
       </div>
    </div>
```

I am adding some data to inner element like

```
$('#inner').data('_key','_someValue');
```

Now some time in future, I am clearing text of outer element.

```
$('#outer').empty().html('some thing new');
```

I am clearing div's text using `empty()`, I read that `empty()` removes all events bound on children elements.

My question is, doe the empty function also remove data from element or we have to do it ourselves like `$('#inner').data('_key',null)` before removing element from DOM or its done automatically by `empty()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From http://api.jquery.com/empty/

> If we had any number of nested elements inside , they would be removed, too. Other jQuery constructs such as data or event handlers are erased as well.

So, from what I understand all data, also the data associated with the child elements will be removed.